# SWIFT: "removeAtIndex" don't work with (sender:UIButton)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, hidden, sender

```
@IBOutlet var items: [UIButton]
@IBAction func itemsHidden(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.hidden = true
    items.removeAtIndex(sender)
    }
```

Hello.

For example, i have array of items.

The code has the error: "Cannot invoke 'removeAtIndex' with an argument list of type (UIButton)".
What i need to do, that "removeAtIndex" works?

Thanks...

Comment: In `removeAtIndex`, you must specify the index of the item you want to remove. For the `sender` you can do `items.indexOf(sender)` to find the index.

Comment: @Spartak please, read crash descriptions yourself before sending them to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `removeAtIndex` method expects to get an index as a parameter.
If you want to remove an object use `func removeObject(_ anObject: AnyObject)`

**EDIT**

There's no `removeObject` in a swift's array (only in `NSMutableArray`).
In order to remove an element, you need to figure out it's index first:

```
if let index = find(items, sender) {
    items.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```

Comment: The Array class does not have a `removeObject(:)` method.

Comment: @Spartak you're welcome. What about accepting the answer? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell us the class of your `items` object.

I assume it's an Array. If not, please let us know.

As Artem points out in his answer, removeAtIndex takes an integer index and remove the object at that index. The index must be between zero and `array.count-1`

There is no `removeObject(:)` method for Swift Array objects because Arrays can contain the same entry at more than one index. You could use the NSArray method `indexOfObject(:)` to find the index of the first instance of your object, and then removeAtIndex.

If you're using Swift 2, you could use the indexOf(:) method, passing in a closure to detect the same object:

```
//First look for first occurrence of the button in the array.
//Use === to match the same object, since UIButton is not comparable
let indexOfButton = items.indexOf{$0 === sender}

//Use optional binding to unwrap the optional indexOfButton
if let indexOfButton = indexOfButton
{
  items.removeAtIndex(indexOfButton)
}
else
{
   print("The button was not in the array 'items'.");
}
```

(I'm still getting used to reading Swift function definitions that include optionals and reference protocols like Generator so the syntax of the above may not be perfect.)